# Eclipse: Could not find or load main class classnotfoundexception (with fix)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have had this problem for years and years now where Eclipse would sometimes, seemingly for no reason, throw this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class [main-class] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [main-class]`

This error fires despite the class being in the file system and having previously worked with no flaws. Project clean does not fix it, and the filepath is completely valid. Consequent Google Searches usually turn up recommending that it's one of those two problems, or that you have to completely delete the project, or create a new workspace - so on.

I'm not sure what the exact cause of this problem is, and I haven't ever really been able to find one neither. However I had found a relatively simple fix for correcting it.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show the content of your launch configuration (share it in the _Commons_ tab to store it as file). Eclipse is just a tool and you are the one using that tool which might give you unexpected or wrong results. So please tell what you did with Eclipse rather than telling _Eclipse would sometimes, seemingly for no reason_ do things. There is a known issue when the module name is changed that leads to this error.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it. Unfortunately I've never been able to trigger this on purpose, but it has happened to be somewhat frequently for the last decade of using Eclipse. That said, it can't be module related because I don't use modules in my current projects and go for a simpler approach. I'll improve this post when I have some time! Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem, what I've learned is that for some reason it tends to be Run Configuration itself. What you can do is:

- Click "Run" in the toolbar
- Click "Debug Configurations"
- Create a new Run Configuration (However, don't just copy and paste the old one - for some reason this doesn't always fix the problem for me)
- Set it up appropriately for the class, you can however copy the parameters from the old
- Save and use that as the new run configuration for your program

This has generally fixed the problem for me most times. Hopefully someday Eclipse will have this properly fixed.

My current Eclipse version is 2021-12 (4.22.0)

I don't know if I did this self-answered question thing correctly, but for those of you who are banging your heads against your keyboard on Google right now trying to fix this, I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a bug report about what you talking about?

Comment: I don't think so, and I've never made one myself due to the fact I've never been able to figure out what causes it specifically. Someone in a comment above mentioned there's a known bug related to module naming, but I don't use modules in my projects. But I'm going to try and look into it and see if I can find a specific reason - it just seems to happen random when I'm simply coding unrelated things. Regardless, I wanted to drop this on Stack since I've never seen this solution recommended despite it working consistently for me.